# Problem in getting values from Json response

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I am hitting a URL with four parameters, If parameters not match I will get the Following response.

This is my JSON response:

```
{
 "result": "0"
}
```

Now my question is. How do I get that result value from response?

Here's, my Retrofit instance

```
public class RetrofitClientInstance {
private static Retrofit retrofit;
private static final String BASE_URL = "https://URL/";

    public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance() {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

Retrofit Interface

```
public interface ApiInterface {

    @GET("f/f/ff.php")
    Call<Object> verifyUser (@QueryMap Map< String, String > params );

}
```

Code for getting the response

```
ApiInterface apiInterface = RetrofitClientInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(ApiInterface.class);

Call<Object> call = apiInterface.verifyUser(params);

call.enqueue(new Callback<Object>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Object> call, Response<Object> response) {

        Log.e("Code ", response.code() + "");
        if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.e("Code ", response.code() + "");
            return;
        }

        // Convert String to json object
        JSONObject json = null;
        String str_value = null;
        try {
            json = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response));
            //JSONObject json_LL = json.getJSONObject("result");


            // get value from LL Json Object
            str_value = json.getString("result"); //<< get value here


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Log.e("Response ", json.length() + "");
        Toast.makeText(RegistrationForm.this, str_value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Object responseBody = response.body();


    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<Object> call, Throwable t) {

        Log.e("Failed", t.getMessage() + "");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `Gson`. You can replace `Object` with a class that holds the fields that you want to parse.

for example:

```
public class ResultResponse {
    String result;

    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(String result) {
        this.result = result;
    }
}
```

And change your endpoint method to return this class.

```
public interface ApiInterface {

    @GET("f/f/ff.php")
    Call< ResultResponse> verifyUser (@QueryMap Map< String, String > params );

}
```

Also don't forget to change the remaining code to use the new return type `ResultResponse`

```
Call<ResultResponse> call = apiInterface.verifyUser(params);

call.enqueue(new Callback<ResultResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResultResponse> call, Response<ResultResponse> response) {

        Log.e("Code ", response.code() + "");
        if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.e("Code ", response.code() + "");
            return;
        }
        ResultResponse resultResponse = response.body();
        String str_value = resultResponse.getResult();
        Toast.makeText(RegistrationForm.this, str_value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<Object> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.e("Failed", t.getMessage() + "");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank You @Mohamed Nagen